# I wonder why the corresponding storage of pytorch.tensor changes every time it is resized?

Tags: python, pytorch, storage

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor([3,2,3,4])
b = a.view(2,2)
c = a.resize(2,2)
d = a.resize_(2,2)
print(id(a.storage()))
print(id(b.storage()))
print(id(c.storage()))
print(id(d.storage()))
```

run at first time

```
2356950450056
2356950450056
2356950450056
2356950450056
```

run at second time

```
2206021857352
2206301638600
2206021857352
2206301638600
```

Why does id change sometimes but not change sometimes, I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. (apologies for my poor English)
**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to view or resize the object to observe this behaviour, calling `storage` on the same object can return different id's:

```py
a = torch.tensor([3,2,3,4])
print(id(a.storage()))
print(id(a.storage()))
>>> 2308579152
>>> 2308422224
```

This is because the python storage object is constructed [when calling](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-is-id-tensors-storage-different-every-time/100478) `.storage()`.